# Why does this author define cardinality indirectly?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, cardinals

I'm studying [Enderton's Elements of Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384407) and in the page 129 he defines what it means two sets being equinumerous:

[image]

After that in the page 136 he defines cardinality:

[image]

Why doesn't he define cardinality directly saying that $card (A)=card(B)$ iff there is a one-to-one function from $A$ onto $B$?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps he wants to make the idea of cardinality more approachable by calling it "equinumerous" first (which has an apparent meaning) and then providing some examples.

Comment: That statement from page $136$ does *not* define cardinality: it only defines what it means for two sets to have the same cardinality.

Comment: To add to Mr. Scott's answer, it is possible to define what $|A|$ of a set is. However, to say that $|A|=|B|$, all one has to do is say that there exists a bijection between those two sets. The notation is a bit tricky because it makes it seems as if the author is defining what $|A|$ is, and then comparing the two cardinalities, he is not doing that. It could be done, which is the reason for the notation, but it is not done so in your book. Simply interpret that "equation", as notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a definition of cardinality, and Enderton does not say it is. What he actually says is that we want to define $\operatorname{card} A$ in such a way as to make $\operatorname{card} A = \operatorname{card} B$ iff $A \approx B$. He goes on to say that there is not a simple way to do this, but (in effect) that he will proceed as if such a definition had been made, while promising that a proper definition will eventually be given. The actual definition of $\operatorname{card} A$ occurs on page 197.

As to Enderton's specific exposition, the notation $A \approx B$ is useful on its own. It's more compact, and you don't have any awkward definitional issues to rigorously justify using it. And once Enderton defined it, it made sense to reuse it to explain the $\operatorname{card}$ notation. This is similar to the general practice of using an already defined concept to define a related concept.